# Remove a vehicle from VRP

Tags: optaplanner

What is the correct way to remove (=delete) a vehicle from planning entity collection (similar to VehicleRoutingSolution.VehicleList in OptaPlanner VRP samples) via ProblemFactChange?

So far I've tried to

- reset nextCustomer before deleting the vehicle
- reset nextCustomer of vehicle and prevStandstill of its first customer
- do the same for all chained customers on vehicle
- brute force through customer list

I'm getting IllegalStateException, either because of mismatch between prevStandstill and nextCustomer or Local Search phase start failing with an uninitialized solution.

Edit: moving the first customer in chain to another vehicle seems to be working fine.

### Edit 2

I tried to reset all customers in chain with this snippet

```
Customer customer = vehicle.getNextCustomer();
while(customer!=null)
{
    Customer nextCustomer = customer.getNextCustomer();
    scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(customer, "previousStandstill");    //Exception on second customer
    customer.setPreviousStandstill(null);
    scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(customer, "previousStandstill");
    scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(customer, "nextCustomer");
    customer.setNextCustomer(null);
    scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(customer, "nextCustomer");
    customer.setVehicle(null);
    customer=nextCustomer;
}
```

but I'm getting hit with IllegalStateException on second run through loop

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The entity (CUST39(after CUST39)) has a variable (previousStandstill) with value (CUST39(after null)) which has a sourceVariableName variable (nextCustomer) with a value (null) which is not that entity.
Verify the consistency of your input problem for that sourceVariableName variable.
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.variable.inverserelation.SingletonInverseVariableListener.retract(SingletonInverseVariableListener.java:82)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.variable.inverserelation.SingletonInverseVariableListener.beforeVariableChanged(SingletonInverseVariableListener.java:44)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.variable.listener.VariableListenerSupport.beforeVariableChanged(VariableListenerSupport.java:145)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(AbstractScoreDirector.java:257)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(AbstractScoreDirector.java:228)
```

It seems obvious (the state is invalid because first customer is detached from second, but second is still pointing at the first one), but I don't know what's the correct route ;) around it.

This

```
    Customer nextCustomer = customer.getNextCustomer();
    customer.setPreviousStandstill(null);
    customer.setNextCustomer(null);
    scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(customer, "previousStandstill");
    scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(customer, "nextCustomer");
    scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(customer, "nextCustomer");
    scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(customer, "previousStandstill");
```

seems to work - CH is fired for each of the removed customers, move count is correct, EasyScore works and the exception is avoided. But, is it bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do all these:

- While each nextCustomer of that vehicle, set that customer's `previousStandstill` (= var) on null and it's `nextCustomer` (= inverse shadow var) also on null and it's `vehicle` (= anchor shadow var) also on null.
- Remove the vehicle from the solution's vehicle list

Make sure to call the before/after methods appropriately.

The customers of that vehicle will then be uninitialized and the solver's CH will initialize them.

Comment: Thanks, the methods are Before/AfterEntityRemoved for vehicle and Before/AfterVariableChanged for each customer variable?