# How do I get the 'current' scoredirector in optaplanner - and does it matter?

Tags: optaplanner, chained

Like in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168756/remove-a-vehicle-from-vrp) I would like to remove entities before solving a Optaplanner problem again(repeated planning).

But I am uncertain of how to get the score director that was used when generating the first solution and of the importance of calling Before/AfterEntityRemoved and Before/AfterVariableChanged on the scoredirector when removing entities?

Suppose I removed a Vehicle AND all the customers that were assigned to it – and I did not already build a scoreDirector myself – could I then just ignore calling methods on a scoredirector and still be able to solve it again with a correctly calculated score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Are you sure that instead of removing entities, you might just want to leave them unassigned? If yes, then do **overconstrainted planning** instead (see docs).

2) If you remove entities *before* giving the solution instance to `solve(Solution s)`, then you can remove them without notifying the ScoreDirector.

3) Removing entities normally changes the planning problem, so that's **real-time planning** (= changing the problem during solving). So if you want to remove entities during solving, it needs to be done in a `addProblemFactChange()`. See the docs on how to get the `ScoreDirector` there and what your notification obligations are.

Comment: 1) Yes, I want to remove them. I solve a plan that goes a few weeks into the future. I do nightly planning and need to remove tasks that was planned for "yesterday" and add a few new tasks to be planned a few weeks ahead.

Comment: 2) Super!

3) Okay. Im not doing realtime planning. I only do nightly planning (+ a little short-while planning when a user make changes that presumably only has little effect on the problem.) I supposed I should consider realtime planning then, but the system will be planning for thousands of different organizations and I only want to spend CPU-cycles when necessary.

Comment: In case of weekly planning, 2) is definitely the way to go. ProblemFactChanges are a complexity one should only deal with if subsecond or second solving time is needed.

Comment: PS: you might not want to remove all historic tasks. Only the really old ones. The recent historic tasks might be needed as "immovable" entities if there are score rules such as "not 10 times the same task type in a row".

Comment: Thanx. Im unable to use immovable entities though. It always gives me the following exception and I haven't figured out why yet:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Replay must occur after record. The recordingEntitySelector (Recording(Filtering(FromSolutionEntitySelector(Visit))))'s next() has not been called yet.

Comment: That exception is related to mimic replay/recording. If indeed using immovable entities triggers this exception, that's probably a bug. Create a jira (see optaplanner.org -> code -> report an issue) and attach a reproducer and I 'll fix it.